# How do I do a limited API call, then once that returns replace with the full API call?

Tags: reactjs, api

I have several API calls that are made when the page opens that fills tiles however they return too much data for the initial load causing a slow load time. This data is still needed though as the page is used. Is there a way I can do a limited API call such as ?limit=24&offset=0, it return the results, fill the tiles, etc. but then trigger a full API call and re-return/refill the arrays etc once complete?

Comment: you can but you need the server side code to take a query string of values you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you can. You should be change the backend API and add pagination
>   to the API, then you can handle load data from API with button or
>   scroll to load more.

**optional**
Also you can use follow package for inifinite scroll with load more:

[infinite scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)

Comment: currently it populates an array with the data and does not do any api calls after the page loads

Comment: First please see this [Best practice to implementing "Infinite Scroll/Load More" feature in react js.](https://hashnode.com/post/best-practice-to-implementing-infinite-scrollload-more-feature-in-react-js-like-hashnodecom-cj29yjedf0016u353pk0oclse) and then see this [doc](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component#readme)